# Tkinter gif loop infinitely increasing speed

Tags: python, tkinter, animated-gif, tkinter-label

I used Tkinter with python to play animation and it works perfectly fine, on launch it has about 25-30 fps. But once I click on label to changed a gif it starts increasing fps with every click. I can't even determine what exactly is causing this issue. I tried changing timeout parameter in `.after()` function and adding `time.sleep()`. Is it a Tkinter bug?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
import random


root = Tk()

class GifAnimation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = root
        self.gif_path = ""
        self.gif_label: Label = None
        self.gif_count = 0
        
        self.gifs_list = [
            "./gifs/gif1.gif",
            "./gifs/gif2.gif",
            "./gifs/gif3.gif",
            "./gifs/gif4.gif",
            "./gifs/gif5.gif"
        ]
    
    def configure(self):
        self.gif_label = Label(self.master)
        self.gif_label.pack()
        self.gif_label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: self.change_gif())
        
        self.gif_path = random.choice(self.gifs_list)
        self.gif_info = Image.open(self.gif_path)
        self.gif_frames = self.gif_info.n_frames
        self.gif_im = [PhotoImage(file=self.gif_path,format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(self.gif_frames)]
    
    def animation(self):
        self.gif_im2 = self.gif_im[self.gif_count]
        self.gif_label.configure(image=self.gif_im2)
        self.gif_count += 1
        if self.gif_count == self.gif_frames:
            self.gif_count = 0
        self.master.after(100, self.animation)
    
    def change_gif(self):
        self.gif_label.destroy() # avoid infitite label creation
        self.gif_count = 0 # reset gif frames
        self.configure() 
        self.animation()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gif = GifAnimation()
    gif.configure()
    gif.animation()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Each time you press  the button, it starts a new `.after` loop that changes the gif while the old one doesn't stop. So the bug is in your code.

Comment: Thank you! ```self.master.after_cancel()``` resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comment, `self.master.after_cancel()` needs to be added.

> after_cancel() function is used to stop the scheduling of the after()function. [*](https://pythonguides.com/python-tkinter-after-method/)

`self.master.after_cancel()` needs the `after()` id (cf  `self.after_id` in `animations`).

Here are the two functions that needs to be modified.

```
def animation(self):
    self.gif_im2 = self.gif_im[self.gif_count]
    self.gif_label.configure(image=self.gif_im2)
    self.gif_count += 1
    if self.gif_count == self.gif_frames:
        self.gif_count = 0
    self.after_id= self.master.after(100, self. Animation)

def change_gif(self):
    self.master.after_cancel(self.after_id)
    self.gif_label.destroy()  # avoid infitite label creation
    self.gif_count = 0  # reset gif frames
    self.configure()
    self. Animation()
```

---

The full working code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
import random


root = Tk()


class GifAnimation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = root
        self.gif_path = ""
        self.gif_label: Label = None
        self.gif_count = 0

        self.gifs_list = [
            r"Z:\TEMP\tabata\gif\0002.gif",
            r"Z:\TEMP\tabata\gif\0003.gif",
            r"Z:\TEMP\tabata\gif\0004.gif",
            r"Z:\TEMP\tabata\gif\0000.gif",
            r"Z:\TEMP\tabata\gif\0001.gif"
        ]

    def configure(self):
        self.gif_label = Label(self.master)
        self.gif_label.pack()
        self.gif_label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: self.change_gif())

        self.gif_path = random.choice(self.gifs_list)
        self.gif_info = Image.open(self.gif_path)
        self.gif_frames = self.gif_info.n_frames
        self.gif_im = [PhotoImage(
            file=self.gif_path, format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(self.gif_frames)]

    def animation(self):
        self.gif_im2 = self.gif_im[self.gif_count]
        self.gif_label.configure(image=self.gif_im2)
        self.gif_count += 1
        if self.gif_count == self.gif_frames:
            self.gif_count = 0
        self.after_id = self.master.after(100, self.animation)

    def change_gif(self):
        self.master.after_cancel(self.after_id)
        self.gif_label.destroy()  # avoid infitite label creation
        self.gif_count = 0  # reset gif frames
        self.configure()
        self.animation()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gif = GifAnimation()
    gif.configure()
    gif.animation()
    root.mainloop()
```